# Numbers required for the 'difficult' badges

Tags: discussion

If you take a look at the list of badges, several of the more challenging ones need an awful lot of votes/views/whatever. I guess that the values were set for SO, but wonder if they are likely to be appropriate here. On the one hand the badges need to mean something, but on the other they should be attainable. In particular, I notice:

- 'Popular question' needs 1000 views.
- 'Notable question' needs 2500 views.
- 'Famous question' needs 10 000 views.
- 'Stellar question' favourited by 100 people.

I wonder if the likely size of the community here will is in line with these values. For all I know it will, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: Let's wait and see. I'd revisit this issue if we don't have *any* "popular questions" in 1 year.

Comment: I think we'll get a few 'popular' ones, as there are at least a couple in the high-hundreds of views. It's more the 'famous' end I wonder about :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are about 200 users with reputation>1 currently, so of course those numbers are way out of our league. But I suggest we wait until the end of beta (and even a few months after the official launch) before we evaluate this, after we get a "feeling" how large the community will become, and how fast it grows.

Comment: Fine with me: I just wanted to note this as 'something to think about'